# Pass a Symbol Between Methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use the value of a symbol in another method that I'm redirecting to. It seems as if I can't access :customer_id from method_2. I'd like to be able to access the value of :customer_id that is set in method_1 from method_2.

```
def method_1
  user = User.find_by(:uid => params[:userid]) # this works
  redirect_to :m2, :customer_id => user.cust_id
end

def method_2
  @cid = params[:customer_id]

  # these don't print the value of customer_id
  Rails.logger.info("Customer ID: #{@cid}")
  Rails.logger.info("Customer ID: #{params[:customer_id]}")
end

# this is the line I have in routes.rb
get 'demo/method_2' => 'demo#method_2', :as => :m2
```

Comment: Your question is about passing parameters between actions in Rails, not about symbols in Ruby (which is straightforward). How do you think about clarifying the title and intent? It would help getting the best help...

Comment: The `redirect_to` syntax may be the issue. You may need the `:action` key? As in: `redirect_to :action => :m2, :id => 5`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, it worked! Also, thanks for helping clarify my question!